# Avoid printing Pdfs

Tags: pdf

I get a Pdf from a WS, then I have to show it but need to hide the print option.

What I get from the WS is an Uri and it is shown with an iframe or embed tag.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The **print** button you see in when previewing your pdf is not from Salesforce but from your browser(specifically pdf viewer).

So its not possible to control the visibility of the button from Salesforce.